# Push Notification kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

how to solve this? 
any ideia?
thanks for any help

```
private var notificationManager: NotificationManager? = null
```

......

```
problem Classifier 'NotificationManager' does not have a companion object, and thus must be initialized here
```

code line ->

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```

code

```
override fun onChildAdded(ds: DataSnapshot, prevChildKey: String?) {

    Log.i(TAG, " child added")
    if(markers.size == 0) {
        pushIssueMarker(ds)
    }
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    builder.setContentTitle("Firebase Push Notification");
    builder.setContentText("Hello this is a test Firebase notification, a new database child has been added");
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager?.notify(1, builder.build());
}
```

Comment: Use the lazy initialisation for notificationManager as once you define the notificationManager you can't change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are coding in Kotlin. So its object creation is different than JAVA.

Change your below line

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```

to this line

```
val notificationManager = getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to break into two lines, you can eaisly initialize it as

```
val mNotificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
```